# Why am I getting TypeError Missing attribute when I haven't specified an attribute in __init__

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I'm confused as to why I'm getting this error as the book that I'm going off of 'Starting out with Python, 3rd edition' shows that I should be able to do this. I'm doing the same thing the book is just naming my classes different.

here are my class definitions:

```
 #parent class
    class Animal:
        def __init__(self,animalType):

            self.setAnimalType(animalType)
            self.setAge(0)
            self.setColor('')

    #mutator functions
    def setAnimalType(self,animalType):
        self.__animalType = animalType

    def setAge(self,age):
        self.__age = age

    def setColor(self,color):
       self.__color = color


    #accessor functions
    def getAnimalType(self):
        return self.__animalType

    def getAge(self):
        return self.__age

    def getColor(self):
        return self.__color

    #stub function
    def makeNoise(self):
        print("Argh")

    #state function
    def __str__(self):
       return 'I am a {} {} being of age {}.\n'.format(self.getColor(),self.getAnimalType(),self.getAge())


#child classes
class Mouse(Animal):
    def __intit__(self):
        Animal.__init__(self,'Mouse')

    def makeNoise(self):
        print("squeak")
```

when i do the following:

```
#import statements
import animals

# functions
def main():
    mouse1 = animals.Mouse()

    mouse1.setAge(5)
    mouse1.setColor('white')
    print(mouse1,mouse1.makeNoise())


# Main Program
main()
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'animalType'
```

Comment: `def __intit__(self)` should be `def __init__(self)`

Comment: Wow, I knew it was something silly like that and I was just missing it.  Thank you.

Comment: Your methods are not within the class definition. Unindent the class definition for `Animal`.